# R Applying user defined function to vector; Indexing within sapply()

Tags: r, indexing, apply, sapply

Unfortunately I am a victim of excessive forlooping. I believe the following calculation can be improved by using the sapply() function within R. However, I am having a few problems with indexing. The following is a calculation for work done per time step of a molecular simulation. Here is the solution in the form of a loop:

```
F1 <- c(0.38603555, 0.06516336, 0.55603406, 0.52901992)
wd <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(F1))
ts <- 0.198
ve <- 0.0015

for(i in 1:length(F1)){

    if(i == 1){
    wd[i] <- (F1[i] * ve * ts)  
    } else {
    wd[i] <- wd[i-1] + (F1[i] * ve * ts) 
    }

}
```

Works perfectly fine. My incorrect attempt in the form of sapply() is as follows:

```
F1[1] <- (F1[1] * ve * ts)
wd    <- sapply(F1[2:length(F1)], function(x) x[-1] + (x * ve * ts))
```

I believe the problem lye's with indexing x. The return class should be a vector.

In reality F1 has several million values, additionally I have several calculations similar to this. Therefore I would appreciate if anyone could suggest an efficient solution.

Best,
Daniel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no performance advantage in using `sapply` here. It's just another loop. Instead use vectorization:

```
all.equal(wd,
          cumsum(F1 * ve * ts)
         )
#[1] TRUE
```

This does the looping in compiled code and is thus faster by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct in that this solution is much more efficient! For comparison on ~100k element vector 0.236s (loop) vs 0.001s (cumsum). I should note that previously in the loop I did not specify the length of vector wd, which significantly increases the efficiency, without; time = 19.385s.